# CKEditor4 Laravel Not Parsing HTML, Rather Outputs the Tags like <p>, <h1> etc

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

My CKEditor displays just fine but when I modify text to be bold, italisized, etc... it doesn't render properly and just outputs with tags like so:

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; <u><em><strong>This is a test of the editor</strong></em></u>
```

I want these styles applied via the editor but it isn't working correctly. I'm using phpMyAdmin to test my website via localhost. This is a fresh installation of CKeditor.

Here is how the form is coded:

```
    <div class="content" style="width: 50%;">
    <h1>Create Post</h1>
    <div class="create-post-form">
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
                {{Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
                {{Form::textarea('body', '', ['id' => 'editor', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body Text'])}}
            </div>
            {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the create function in my controller:

```
        //creating the posting
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post created successfully!');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the correct behavior for CKEditor.  If you ask it to give you formatted HTML, it will store the data in the DB/variable exactly as you have shown above.

If you are asking to *render* to the page from Laravel's Blade along with the styles you have set, this is where you will need to make a change.  If you are seeing the HTML tags, you are escaping the text.

Change

`{{ $yourTextFromCKEditorPassedFromYourController }}`

To:

`{!! $yourTextFromCKEditorPassedFromYourController !!}`

Standard warnings should be heeded here for displaying entries without cleaning or escaping if they are from an un-trusted source

Comment: This is what mine looks like, similar to what you've suggested:                                                 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

Comment: That's your form code.  What does your display text look like where you are rendering the HTML with the tags?

Comment: for example, i'll type up a paragraph of an article i'm writing into the CKeditor. i'll select a few sections to make bold, etc... then once i've submitted, the output in my HTML doesn't render the bold style, rather includes those HTML tags. Inspect element just shows the tags also. it isn't parsing any HTML.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  The problem is exactly what I'm saying in my answer.  What is the code to display the output?  IE after you submit, and you view the HTML as you say - what is the code that is displaying this wrong HTML?  That's what needs to be fixed - you need to remove the escapes at this point.

Comment: $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->save();

Comment: OK, that's your save code.  What we need to find is the code you are sending to show your characters.  The display code.  Or are you saying that you are looking at the tags in the `$post` model and NOT displaying it?  If that's the case, there is nothing wrong - it will store the HTML tags in the `$post->body`.  When you *display* them to the page, if you use the blade `{!! $post->body !!}}` it will display with the correct style and not show the HTML tags.

Comment: I've changed the PostsController function to {!! $post->body !!} but it is now saying syntax error unexpected '!'

Comment: That's because that isn't PHP, it is the display code for your Blade view file.

Comment: that was the answer. edited my show blade. thanks watercayman